# How do I use xhost for this situation?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to make an autonomous drone using the Robot Operating System ([ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System)). To do this, I have installed **Raspbian Lite** (**Jessie**) on a **Rasperry Pi 3** and am currently using **ROS Kinetic** on it. I decided to go with **Openbox Window Manager** and installed a terminal onto it for convenience. I can just call `sudo startx`. Since it is a system-wide terminal, I have also installed **tmux** for convenience. I am running the xserver on a particular pane and conduct my ROS work on other panes.

Now when I try to run commands that call on a GUI application from my system-wide terminal, I get the error:

```
QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted
```

After a recommendation from [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333046/how-to-connect-to-a-xserver-from-my-system-wide-terminal) question, I decided to install `xhost` on my terminal emulator. After invoking `xhost +` in the same emulator, I get this:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

After which I invoke xhost which returns with:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
SI:localuser:root
```

Therefore, within my system-wide terminal, I have set the environmental variable to 5 different values which have been listed below, and tried to run the program which calls on the `$DISPLAY`, but I get the same `QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display` error.

```
SI:localuser:root 
localuser:root 
localuser 
root 
SI:localuser
localhost:0
```

The last one was actually from the linked question. To my understanding, I am doing exactly what is listed out in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xhost-1.html) man page. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Extra notes**

Currently my remote drone isn't flying at all. I am programming on the Raspberry Pi completely as of now. So therefore, the only way, that I can get a GUI screen is to output the GUI of the window manager from a [kernel virtual terminal device](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333757/what-is-switching-environments-on-the-system-wide-terminal-called). I want to know how I can connect from one virtual device to the other using xhost. Should I do this over the internet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250986/how-do-i-use-xhost-for-this-situation?/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2016-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm not completely sure, what you want to do :-(

First of all I need to know proper names:
Drone + ControlPC

My ControlPC has X-Windows-Server running and I enable remote display access with: `xhost +`

Now my remote drone  is allowed to open a graphics display at my ControlPC.

From the ControlPC you can do now a simple `ssh -C -X <drone ip address>` to access the drone.
When you start now inside the ssh session a graphical application the output window will be shown at you ControlPC.

Is this what you want to do ?

Happy hacking
Cheers
Christian

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-04**:
Hey, sorry about my late reply. Just added some info to the question to clear a few things out.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-04**:
I cannot ssh into my drone, since I don't have a control PC to start with.